# Python inheritance with functions without running function

Tags: python

Say if I had this:

```
def player():
    your_player = Character()
    battle(your_player) # <-- automatically runs battle - I DONT WANT THIS

def battle(your_player):
    #etc
def main(): # I want the functions to be ran in this function
    # not in any other functions
    player()
    battle()
```

But, I wanted it to make it so that when the variable gets inherited, it doesn't run, so it can all run in a single main function.

How can I do this?

If I haven't explained it clearly, just ask.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give a more robust example of the desired behaviour.

Comment: When I inherit a variable to be used in another function, it automatically runs the function. I want it so that it doesn't do that, and it runs it when I say so in another function

Comment: It sounds like you are asking if `battle` can be an inline function? There is no inheritance in your example.

Comment: Nothing is run automatically. If you don't want `battle` to run when you call `player`, don't call it from the body of `player`.

Comment: For a start there is no 'inheritance' in this code. Secondly, why don't you just have the `player` function return the `your_player` instance to `main` and call `battle(your_player)` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is for `battle` to be a method of the `Character` class. You can add it to the definition like so:

```
class Character:
    # rest of definition
    def battle(self):
        # definition of battle function
```

And then use it like

```
def main():
    player = Character()
    player.battle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is usually related to classes.

```
battle(your_player)
```

is a function call.

```
your_player = Character()
```

is an instanciation of the object your_player from the class Character.

So is really is NO inheritance at all in your example.